# pyspark - request.post json from view not working

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, powerbi

I´m a newbie to spark. Hopefully this is not too silly question.

I´m trying to call the Power BI admin API endpoint PostWorkspaceInfo.

The endpoint needs a list of modified workspaces as body. I have created all the logic to get a list of the modified workspace guids and I have put them into batches so I can call the PostWorkspaceInfo endpoint to ask for the metadata. My problem is that the list over modified workspaces is coming from a temporary view and when I try to pass it to the json part of the request.post it fails with BadRequest. I have examined the content of the column and it´s exactly as it should be. If I copy it and paste it straight into the request.post the call works. For some reason the text I´m inputting from the view is not read correctly. I´m guessing that I need to somehow make the request.post parse it as JSON but I have no idea how.

For this question I have limited the number of workspaces to 3 and sanitized the guids. Normally I would have hundreds/thousands of workspaces in batches of 100 hence the for loop below.

The column BodyExpression from below returns this:
{"workspaces": ["034c87da-bbbb-4df8-becc-555e5916d6fa","043654b6-7868-aaaa-bdad-b1cf9ad95f4c","073c7513-dddd-40c3-bb6e-48d0f0b00b42"]}

```
post_WorkspaceInfoUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/workspaces/getInfo?lineage=True&datasourceDetails=True&getArtifactUsers=True&datasetSchema=True&datasetExpressions=True"

dfbatches = spark.sql("SELECT Batch, BodyExpression FROM WorkspaceBatches")

rows_looped = dfbatches.select("Batch", "BodyExpression").collect()

for rows in rows_looped:
    post_WorkspaceInfo = requests.post(url=post_WorkspaceInfoUrl, headers=header, json = rows.BodyExpression )
    print(post_WorkspaceInfo.text)
```

The code above runs but the response is a bad request:
{"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Bad Request","details":[{"message":"Error converting value "{"workspaces": ["034c87da-bbbb-4df8-becc-555e5916d6fa","043654b6-7868-aaaa-bdad-b1cf9ad95f4c","073c7513-dddd-40c3-bb6e-48d0f0b00b42"]}" to type 'Microsoft.PowerBI.ServiceContracts.Api.RequiredWorkspaces'. Path '', line 1, position 3096.","target":"requiredWorkspaces"}]}}

When I run the below code the response is correct:

```
post_WorkspaceInfoUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/workspaces/getInfo?lineage=True&datasourceDetails=True&getArtifactUsers=True&datasetSchema=True&datasetExpressions=True"

dfbatches = spark.sql("SELECT Batch, BodyExpression FROM WorkspaceBatches")

rows_looped = dfbatches.select("Batch", "BodyExpression").collect()

for rows in rows_looped:
    post_WorkspaceInfo = requests.post(url=post_WorkspaceInfoUrl, headers=header, json = {"workspaces": ["034c87da-bbbb-4df8-becc-555e5916d6fa","043654b6-7868-aaaa-bdad-b1cf9ad95f4c","073c7513-dddd-40c3-bb6e-48d0f0b00b42"]} )
    print(post_WorkspaceInfo.text)
```

I tried converting the BodyExpression to JSON and then passing it into the request.post but it didn´t work. I´ve tried all kinds of conversions but nothing works for me.

I´m expecting that the string I pass into would work the same way as when I paste the same string directly into the function.

I realize it might be hard to figure this out without testing it so here is all my code. Only thing that is missing is the app id and secret.

```
#Import necessary libraries
import msal
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta, time

#Set Client ID and Secret for Service Principal
client_id = ""
client_secret = ""
authority_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/northinsights.com"
scope = ["https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default"]

activityDate = date.today()

#Use MSAL to grab token
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, authority=authority_url, client_credential=client_secret)
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)


#Set URL for changed workspaces
url = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/workspaces/modified"

#Get changed workspaces
if 'access_token' in result:
    access_token = result['access_token']
    header = {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':f'Bearer {access_token}'}
    api_call = requests.get(url=url, headers=header)
    print(json.loads(api_call.text))

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(json.loads(api_call.text))
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("modifiedworkspaces")
display(df1)

%%sql
--Batch workspace ids into 100

create or replace temporary view WorkspaceBatches as
WITH WorkspaceRanked AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY id) AS Rank
    , id
    FROM modifiedworkspaces
),
WorkspaceBatched AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY(Rank % 100) ORDER BY Rank ASC) AS Batch
    , id
    FROM WorkspaceRanked
)

SELECT replace(concat('{"workspaces": ["' , array_join(array_sort(collect_set(id)),","),'"]}'),',','","')  AS BodyExpression, Batch
--INTO WorkspaceBatches
FROM WorkspaceBatched
GROUP BY Batch;



SELECT * FROM WorkspaceBatches


#Try to post workspaces to get inventory
post_WorkspaceInfoUrl = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/workspaces/getInfo?lineage=True&datasourceDetails=True&getArtifactUsers=True&datasetSchema=True&datasetExpressions=True"
dfbatches = spark.sql("SELECT Batch, BodyExpression FROM WorkspaceBatches")
#display(dfbatches2)
rows_looped = dfbatches.select("Batch", "BodyExpression").collect()
# looping through each batch
for rows in rows_looped:
    #print(rows.value)
    post_WorkspaceInfo = requests.post(url=post_WorkspaceInfoUrl, headers=header, json = rows.BodyExpression )
    print(post_WorkspaceInfo.text)
```

Comment: The answer was so simple as data = rows.BodyExpression instead of json = rows.bodyexpression

Answer (score 0):

The answer was so simple as, made below change

`data = rows.BodyExpression` instead of `json = rows.bodyexpression`